# vim script about concating a variable and a const string

Tags: string, vim, concatenation

I'm writing a function in my `~/.vimrc` file, but I got a problem.
I want to concat a variable and a const string, so I do this like below:

```
let linux_version=system('uname -r')
let host_kernel_dir= "/lib/modules/" . linux_version . "/build"
echo host_kernel_dir
```

I wanted result is `/lib/modules/4.8.0-52-generic/build`, but I got this result

```
"/lib/modules/4.8.0-52-generic

/build "
```

So it seems a `\n` was added. So how to get rid of this `\n`?

Comment: my vim version is 7.4

Answer (score 3):

**This removes newlines from the system output**

```
let linux_version = substitute(system('uname -r'), '\n\+$', '', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

`system()` result must be *chomped* (for those who have known perl), I use the following:

```
function! lh#os#system(cmd)
  return system(a:cmd)[:-2]
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using /proc pseudo filesystem:

`let linux_version=readfile('/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease')[0]`